# Array formatting of JSON objects with key values

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

I have an array with below format, I am trying to remove duplicate keys and merge it to one. Please let me know how to achieve this.

```
[
  {"tablename":"table1","tablecolumns":"yes"},
  {"tablename":"table1","columnname":"column1"},
  {"tablename":"table1","columnname":"col2"},
  {"tablename":"table2","tablecolumns":"yes"},
  {"tablename":"table2","columnname":"column3"},
  {"tablename":"table2","columnname":"col4"}
]
```

expected format:

```
[
    {"tablename":"table1","tablecolumns":"yes","columnname":"column1","columnname":"col2"},
    {"tablename":"table2","tablecolumns":"yes","columnname":"column3","columnname":"col4"}
]
```

Comment: I guess you can't have `columnname` twice as a property for one object as you expect in your result format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce` method:

```
const result = arr.reduce((a, {tablename, tablecolumns, columnname}) => {
  a[tablename] = a[tablename] || {tablename, tablecolumns, columnnames: []};
  if (columnname)
    a[tablename].columnnames.push(columnname);
  return a;
},{})
```

An example:

```js
let arr = [
  { "tablename": "table1", "tablecolumns": "yes" },
  { "tablename": "table1", "columnname": "column1" },
  { "tablename": "table1", "columnname": "col2" },
  { "tablename": "table2", "tablecolumns": "yes" },
  { "tablename": "table2", "columnname": "column3" },
  { "tablename": "table2", "columnname": "col4" }
];


const result = arr.reduce((a, {tablename, tablecolumns, columnname}) => {
  a[tablename] = a[tablename] || {tablename, tablecolumns, columnnames: []};
  if (columnname)
    a[tablename].columnnames.push(columnname);
  return a;
},{})

console.log(Object.values(result));
```

UPDATE:

If you have an additional tag `datatype`, then you can use the following code snippet:

```js
let arr = [
    {"tablename":"table1","tablecolumns":"yes"},
    {"tablename":"table1","columnname":"col1","datatype":"Alphabetic"},
    {"tablename":"table2","tablecolumns":"yes"},
    {"tablename":"table2","columnname":"tabl2_colu","datatype":null},
    {"tablename":"table2","columnname":"tab2_col2","datatype":"Numeric"}
];

const result = arr.reduce((a, {tablename, tablecolumns, columnname, datatype}) => {
    a[tablename] = a[tablename] || {tablename, tablecolumns, columns: []};
    if (columnname)
      a[tablename].columns.push({columnname, datatype});
    return a;
  },{})
console.log(Object.values(result));
```

Comment: thanks @StepUp   for your answer.. if i want add additional tag in column how to add that.. we will get another tag in column  "datatype":"AlphaNumeric"  its dynamically added . i need to have the values each column tags .. can i get in below format ..
thanks for your help once again..
[{"tablename":"table name"},[{"columnname":"column1","datatype":"AlphaNumeric"},{"columnname":"couln2","datatype":null} ],
     {"tablename":"table name2"},[{"columnname":"tab_column1","datatype":"AlphaNumeric"},{"tab_columnname2":"couln2","datatype":null} ]
     ]

Comment: tried with updated code its only pushing column names, please let me know how can i achieve below format ...
[
{"tablename":"table name"},[{"columnname":"column1","datatype":"AlphaNumeric"},{"columnname":"couln2","datatype":null} ],
{"tablename":"table name2"},[{"columnname":"tab_column1","datatype":"AlphaNumeric"},{"tab_columnname2":"couln2","datatype":null} ]]

Comment: @user2319726 how is it possible to know what `[  {"columnname":"column1", "datatype":"AlphaNumeric"},  {"columnname":"couln2", "datatype":null} ]` has `tableName`?

Comment: below is the array i am having right now.. every column object will have table name in it ..


[{"tablename":"table1","tablecolumns":"yes"},{"tablename":"table1","columnname":"col1","datatype":"Alphabetic"},{"tablename":"table2","tablecolumns":"yes"},{"tablename":"table2","columnname":"tabl2_colu","datatype":null},{"tablename":"table2","columnname":"tab2_col2","datatype":"Numeric"}]

Comment: thanks for the answer.. yes its working .. appreciate your help.

Comment: @user2319726  I am glad it helps to you!  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers   :)

Comment: I need to delete the column from the result .. i will get the column name dynamically .. could you please help me how to delete the column and its corresponding object  based on column name ....  {"columnname":"couln2", "datatype":null}

Comment: @user2319726 Hi! Could you create a new post as it is good practise at stackoverflow.com to have one question per post?

Answer (score 0):

So I have mentioned in my comment below your question you can't have the same property name for an object as you expect - `columnname`.

Instead I suggest to have a different structure and store the column names in an array.

Like the following:

```js
const data = [
    {"tablename":"table1","tablecolumns":"yes"},
    {"tablename":"table1","columnname":"column1"},
    {"tablename":"table1","columnname":"col2"},
    {"tablename":"table2","tablecolumns":"yes"},
    {"tablename":"table2","columnname":"column3"},
    {"tablename":"table2","columnname":"col4"}
];

const result = data.reduce((a,c) => {
  const foundelem = a.find(e => e.tablename === c.tablename);
  
  if (foundelem) {
    foundelem.columnnames.push(c.columnname);
  } else {
    a.push({
      tablename: c.tablename,
      tablecolumns: c.tablecolumns,
      columnnames: []
    });
  }
  
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: thanks for your answer and help.

how can i change it to below format ..
[{"tablename":"table name"},[{"columnname":"column1","datatype":"AlphaNumeric"},{"columnname":"couln2","datatype":null} ],
     {"tablename":"table name2"},[{"columnname":"tab_column1","datatype":"AlphaNumeric"},{"tab_columnname2":"couln2","datatype":null} ]
     ]